# How to select 3 row per category in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

I have a table which have a lot of data, it's have a category ID and postId, I need to read 3 new post per category with same CatID.

it's not duplicate of the question suggest by other people. Please check that in my question the postid catid can be anything when in duplicate question it's calculate before running query.

What I have written is

```
SELECT
    MAX(` postid `) AS p1,
    ` catid ` AS c1
FROM
    ` postcategory `
GROUP BY
    ` catid
```

I can put 2 other query in it union distinct but it will make a query a lot big. Is there any good way to do this in MySQL. What I am looking for reading 3 postId (maximum) belong to same category.

```
postId   catId  
------  --------
     9         3
    15         3
    16         3
    17         3
    18         3
    19         5
    20         8
    21         6
    22         8
    23         6
    46         6
    46         8
    26         3
    25         3
    27         5
    28         3
    37         6
    39        10
    40         6
    41         6
    42         6
    43         6
    44         5
    45        11
    63         6
    64         5
    65         6
    66         6
    68         6
```

Comment: search for *select n per group*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select the first n rows per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168834/mysql-select-the-first-n-rows-per-group)

Comment: Google "mysql top N rows group"

Comment: Hello all, Please help me run this http://pastebin.com/rNV6rctG

Comment: what is your desire output with that data?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The postid which is bigger will be selected and I need 3 postid per cat for example I need to select all of them but 3 postid per category. Thanks in advanced

Comment: I mean you should include the result as a data table same as your source data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read 3 new post from each category Using the below query.

```
SELECT
    p1.postId,
    p1.catId
FROM
    postcategory p1
JOIN postcategory p2 ON p1.catId = p2.catId
AND p2.postId >= p1.postId
GROUP BY
    p1.postId,
    p1.catId
HAVING
    COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY
    catId,
    postId
```

Here you can see the [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/IDDUAN44497)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hello @Faisal,  I remove the postcategory table and now all category stored directly in post table. please check this one http://pastebin.com/wy47Midj