# VB.Net Converting Lambda to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, lambda

I've spent the entire day trying to convert this VB.Net code into SQL script. The goal is to remove the VB code and switch to stored procedures:

```vb
Dim hashmap = getHashMap()
Dim x = hashmap.Where(Function(i) Not i.Name.ToLower.Contains("john"))
Dim y = x.GroupBy(Function(i) i.City)
Dim z = y.Select(Function(grp) grp.First()).ToList
```

So far, I've translated everything but the last line (`Dim z = y.Select(Function(grp) grp.First()).ToList`):

```sql
SELECT City FROM hashmap WHERE LOWER(Name) NOT LIKE '%john%' GROUP BY City
```

Comment: So what is the problem? exception message? wrong result?

Comment: I've translated everything but the last statement (y.Select(Function(grp) grp.First()).ToList) to SQL

Comment: It is easier to write SQL off a description of what the code needs to achieve rather than off actual code. As far as I understand the code returns one random hasmap value per city. If that is the case, you want to see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12113699/11683, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19168834/11683 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129693/11683.

Comment: You're right. Sometimes the most challenging requirement is "Make it work as it is working today".